# ¿Como crear modelo con usuario logueado por defecto en Django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, djangorestframework

Básicamente lo que quiero, es crear un modelo `Reserva` con un campo `empleado_de_turno`, que por defecto sea el usuario que inicio sesión en ese momento. Usando la vista genérica `CreateView`.

Entonces cada vez que vaya a crear una instancia del modelo `Reserva`, el campo `empleado_de_turno` ya debe tener asignado el usuario que inicio sesión en ese momento. Algo así seria ideal:

```
class Reserva(models.Model):
    cliente = models.CharField()
    empleado_de_turno = models.ForeignKey(User, default= #usuario_logueado )
```

Gracias por la ayuda, soy nuevo por aqui.

Comment: eso no se hace en el modelo, se hace en la vista

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para establecer en el campo `empleado_de_turno` el usuario que inicio sesión, tendrías que importar el usuario, obtenerlo con un `get()`, etc.

Pero en mi opinión eso es de mala practica ademas de que no se si funcione.

Una solución que se aproxima a la solución de tu problema seria que una ves se crea un usuario, crear una instancia del modelo que del cual estas hablando, para hacerlo tenemos que trabajar con señales, de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from .models import MyModel

    @receiver(post_save, sender = User)
    def receiver(sender, instance, **kwargs):
        if kwargs.get('created'):
            # Obtenemos la instancia del usuario que se creo
            user = User.objetcs.get(username = instance)

            # Creamos una instancia del modelo y asignamos valores a los respectivos campos
            MyModel.objects.get_or_create(empleado_de_turno = user)
```

Así cada ves que se crea un usuario, se crea una instancia de dicho modelo, asignando así los respectivos valores a los campos del modelo y entre ellos asignando el usuario creado a la `ForeignKey`(`empleado_de_turno`).

Otra solución que se me ocurre es asignar el usuario a la `ForeignKey`(`empleado_de_turno`), en una vista, especificamente cuando tu lo veas necesario, y seria de la siguiente manera:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from .models import MyModel

def view(request):
    # Obtenemos la instancia del usuario que inicio sesion
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username = request.user)

    # Obtenemos la instancia a modificar
    instance = get_object_or_404(MyModel, .....)

    # Asignamos el usuario que esta loggeado
    instance.empleado_de_turno = user

    # Guardamos la instancia
    instance.save() 

    ...
```

O bien podrías crear la instancia, pero después tendrías que modificara para seguir asignando los demás usuarios cuando se a necesario.

```
from .models import MyModel
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def view(request):

    # Obtenemos la instancia del usuario que inicio sesion
    user = get_object_or_404(User, username = request.user)

    # Creamos la instancia
    MyModel.objects.create(empleado_de_turno = user)

    ...
```

**Actualisacion:**

De acuerdo a la actualización de tu pregunta, pues seria así la vista `CreateView`:

```
class ReservaCreateView(CreateView):
    model = Reserva
    template_name = 'myapp/example.html'
    fields = ['cliente']
    success_url = reverse_lazy('name')

    def form_valid(self, form):
        user = User.objects.get(username = self.request.user)
        Reserva.objects.create(cliente = self.request.POST['cliente'], empleado_de_turno = user)
        return redirect(self.success_url)
```

Funciona, pero no estoy seguro si es de buena practica mi solución, ya que intente solucionarlo por los métodos, `post`, `get_form`, `get_form_kwargs` y no lo logre y esta solución no me convence del todo.

Bueno si quieres modificar el formulario tendrás que crear un formulario personalizado en el `forms.py` para así que se vea mejor, espero haberte ayudado.

Comment: Muchas gracias por el tiempo, reformule mejor la pregunta ahora, ya que no quiero crear una Reserva al crear un User, y quiero saber como hacerlo con la vista genérica CreateView. Si se puede asignar un default a un CharField no entiendo por que no se puede hacer con un  ForeignKey , gracias nuevamente

Comment: OK ya edite mi respuesta.

Comment: Gracias Julio! Me sirvió tu orientación, buena practica o no de momento me sacaste un dolor de cabeza , saludos!

Comment: OK, saludos!!!!